# Performance issue with my MYSQL query with subqueries

Tags: mysql, performance

I have a huge performance issue with my below query I figured that what is the leakage but don't know how to go around it.

the issue is that inner selects go through all the records in tables which is like 200K and then try to select and apply the filter to it so the whole data get selected in the first round.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 
        ( SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(tp.login) login
              FROM tp
              WHERE tp.user_id = ue.user_id ) login, 
        u.email as email, 
        ue.fname as name 
    FROM user_extra ue
    LEFT JOIN users u ON u.id = ue.user_id 
) t
WHERE 
    email like '%sradesign.net@gmail.com%'
    OR fname like '%test%'
    OR login like '%461988%
```

Comment: All subqueries are excess. Convert this to a query without subqueries.

Comment: If I knew how I wouldn't ask please show me how if you know

Comment: Do you really need in **all** logins concatenated if only one of them matches `'%461988%'`?

Comment: those likes are sample they will be dynamic so for example if a user fills in %461988% I need to know this login first belong to whom and second what is his name and email. so in order to do it, the only idea that came to my mind is to have a column holding the login of each user.

Comment: show output of `explain SELECT ... rest of your query` and `show create table tp`, `show create table user_extra`, `show create table users`

Comment: with OR'd LIKE conditions like this, I don't see how you avoid having to go through all the  records, but there may be a way to do it better

Comment: The `OR` expression will force a table-scan. The `LIKE '%pattern%'` expressions will force a table-scan. There are multiple ways this query will never have good performance. You need to substantially rethink what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test does I have not made a mistake:

```sql
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(tp.login) login,
       u.email as email, 
       ue.fname as name
FROM user_extra ue
JOIN users u ON u.id = ue.user_id    -- I doubt in LEFT
JOIN tp ON tp.user_id = ue.user_id
GROUP BY ue.fname,
         u.email
    -- , ue.user_id -- maybe needed, but I doubt
HAVING email like '%sradesign.net@gmail.com%'
    OR fname like '%test%'
    OR login like '%461988%
```

This is intermediate variant - it must be divided on two (or maybe three - depends on your data) separate queries combined with UNION later.

---

> sometimes it happens that one user doesn't have any login(there is no record for him in tp table) but I want to show him if the customer search term matched in the email of fname how to do this? – Ali Mahmoudi
>
> In such case this table must be joined using outer joining (LEFT JOIN). – Akina
>
> with left join again become like before performance issue the query run for 200 Second – Ali Mahmoudi

As I have said above - this is intermediate variant. If it is correct then let's divide taking into account possible absence in `tp`:

```sql
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(tp.login) login,
           u.email as email, 
           ue.fname as name
    FROM user_extra ue
    JOIN users u ON u.id = ue.user_id    -- I doubt in LEFT
    LEFT JOIN tp ON tp.user_id = ue.user_id
    WHERE u.email like '%sradesign.net@gmail.com%'
    GROUP BY ue.fname,
             u.email
UNION ALL
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(tp.login) login,
           u.email as email, 
           ue.fname as name
    FROM user_extra ue
    JOIN users u ON u.id = ue.user_id    -- I doubt in LEFT
    LEFT JOIN tp ON tp.user_id = ue.user_id
    WHERE ue.fname like '%test%'
    GROUP BY ue.fname,
             u.email
UNION ALL
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(tp.login) login,
           u.email as email, 
           ue.fname as name
    FROM user_extra ue
    JOIN users u ON u.id = ue.user_id    -- I doubt in LEFT
    JOIN tp ON tp.user_id = ue.user_id
    GROUP BY ue.fname,
             u.email
    HAVING login like '%461988%
```

Test its output for correctness.

If it will produce duplicates then replace UNION ALL with UNION DISTINCT.

Comment: Your query works perfectly but I got a problem here now sometimes it happens that one user doesn't have any login(there is no record for him in `tp` table) but I want to show him if the customer search term matched in the email of fname how to do this?

Comment: @AliMahmoudi In such case this table must be joined using outer joining (LEFT JOIN).

Comment: with left join again become like before performance issue the query run for 200Second

Comment: @AliMahmoudi What is the amount of rows returned by these 2 queries?

Comment: 382 total, Query took 187.7294 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

- You seem to have an extra layer of `SELECTs`.  This causes an extra temp table that contains a huge amount of data.
- Unnecessary use of `LEFT` adds confusion and may prevent some optimizations.
- Leading wildcards prevent usage of index.
- `OR` is hard to optimize.  But...

A common trick for optimizing `OR`:

```
( SELECT ... WHERE email like '%sradesign.net@gmail.com%' )
UNION DISTINCT
( SELECT ... WHERE fname like '%test%' )
UNION DISTINCT
( SELECT ... WHERE login like '%461988% )
```

However, because of the `JOINs`, `UNION` may not be practical.

Consider using `FULLTEXT` instead of `LIKE`.